# More efficient way to get used linux ports

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I need a small daemon that monitors open tcp ports currently connected to an Ubuntu Server v14. The idea is that there are many scripts running at a time which need this info in as close to real time as possible and I don't want them all using resources to do the same thing. What I have to get this so far is this:

```
netstat -ln | grep LISTEN | grep tcp6 | awk {print $4} | cut -c 4-
```

My idea is to have this run in a background daemon and update some file which can be read. How can I make this more efficient & relatively simply. Any script or compiled language that sits on Ubuntu Server 14 is fine. I don't need info on how to make a daemon just how to extract the ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need is in one file, you don't need to execute netstat:

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 5434440 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0                   
   1: 0100007F:0277 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 151286810 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
   ...
```

The addresses and ports are in hex.  The listening ports are those where `rem_address` is all zeros.

If all your processes are in the same language, a common function to look at port bindings, would be cheap to run.  (Rather than the complication of an intermediate file.)

Comment: Awesome, this works. One note is that the ports for me mapped back to the local_address column though.